# Changing blocks of values in a large matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have large matrix of 1000x1000 entries. The 1's are organized in blocks, they always seperated from the other blocks by not overlapping on the row or column of the next block. To give you an example with a 12x12 matrix that consists of 3 blocks of 1s:

```
      111100000000
      111100000000
      111100000000
      111100000000
      000011110000
      000011110000
      000011110000
      000011110000
      000000001111
      000000001111
      000000001111
      000000001111
```

I want R to transfer the matrix into something like this(no matter the size of the matrix):

```
      111100000000
      111100000000
      111100000000
      111100000000
      000022220000
      000022220000
      000022220000
      000022220000
      000000003333
      000000003333
      000000003333
      000000003333
```

Thanks in advance!

**Data**

```
structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1), .Dim = c(12L, 12L))
```

Comment: First, it is better to post actual R output for easy reporoducibility, secondly, will the first block of ones always start in the upper left corner?

Comment: Do you know the indices of the 1s in the matrix? ie are the blocks always 4x4 (or do you always know the size of the blocks in advance)?

Comment: On second thought the assumption is not necessary. you said the blocks are non-overlapping.

Comment: Consider amending your question and/or example to reflect your actual problem. Also, you haven't said whether you know the (variable) block size in advance - this saves a bit of footwork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the matrix by the block group. 0's will remain the same and ones will take their group value:

```
len <- sum(mat[,1])
mat * rep(1:(nrow(mat)/len), each=len)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
# [1,]     1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
# [2,]     1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
# [3,]     1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
# [4,]     1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
# [5,]     0    0    0    0    2    2    2    2    0     0     0     0
# [6,]     0    0    0    0    2    2    2    2    0     0     0     0
# [7,]     0    0    0    0    2    2    2    2    0     0     0     0
# [8,]     0    0    0    0    2    2    2    2    0     0     0     0
# [9,]     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3     3     3     3
# [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3     3     3     3
# [11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3     3     3     3
# [12,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3     3     3     3
```

**Edit**

If the block groups vary within the matrix we will have to differentiate one block ending and another beginning using this instead:

```
library(data.table)
mat * rleid(apply(mat, 1, paste, collapse=""))
```

Comment: It almost worked, the matrix looks now like this (I can't post the original output because the matrix is too big):

Comment: Is it a square matrix? `nrow(mat) == ncol(mat)` should be `TRUE` Also `length(unique(colSums(mat))) == 1L` should also be `TRUE`

Comment: It almost worked, the matrix looks now like this (I can't post the original output because the matrix is too big):

    112200000000
    112200000000
    112200000000
    112200000000
    000033440000
    000033440000

etc. so the blooks were detected but the numbers didn't change correctly in my example.

Comment: The first test is TRUE, the second one is FALSE.

Comment: Something in your data does not follow the description you gave. Just troubleshoot. What do you get with `mean(rowSums(mat))` and `mean(colSums(mat))`? They should be the same. Also `unique(mat)` should only be `0 1`.

Comment: > mean(rowSums(zero_matrix))
[1] 17.26382
> mean(colSums(zero_matrix))
[1] 17.26382

Comment: You seem to have some overlapping blocks.

Comment: How many digits are in each block of 1's in the dataset you are working with?

Comment: The number of digits in blocks is variable, sometimes it's 23x23, sometimes just 10x10. I looked into the raw data and of the blocks that can be displayed (the matrix is just too large) none of the block were overlapping.

Comment: OK, so it seems your block size is variable throughout the matrix. Do you know in advance what it is?

Comment: If the block groups vary within the matrix, this answer will have to be changed

Comment: unique(zero_matrix) just turns out the whole matrix, not the unique values in it which is strange.

Comment: Ok, sorry that I didn't mention it but yeah the block  size is variable.

Comment: Yes it used a special matrix method. Try `unique(as.vector(mat))`

Comment: Both turn out 0  1

Comment: Assuming no other undocumented features of your actual matrix, use `bs = rle(rowSums(mat))$lengths` to get your block lengths; and `rep(1:length(bs), bs)` to multiply your matrix by.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee trying that on the example doesn't work

Comment: We haven't differentiated groups with the same size

Comment: I guess that takes us back to a question I've asked twice with no answer yet - **is the block size known in advance**?

Comment: I found a way with `data.table::rleid`. Just paste the rows together as an id

Comment: @mathematical.coffee your suggestion worked! bs = rle(rowSums(mat))$lengths and rep(1:length(bs), bs).
It replaced the numbers correctly :)

Comment: @PCK1992 it will not work if you have two blocks of the same size next to each other. Please answer my question - it would save us much work.

Comment: I don't know the group size in advance. There might be cases of two groups of the same size at different positions in the dataset.

Comment: Ok so I found two neighboring blocks with 14x14. Both blocks 1's were replaced with the same number.

Comment: Did you guys check the edit? It works without the groups predefined.